# How to get all possible exceptions from a block?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to determine all possible exceptions that might be raised in a code block? (e.g. Some logic that suggests some specific exceptions to catch based on the code block instead of just raising that exception is too generic.

```
    try:
        m = check_output(["dd", "--version"]).decode()
        ver_line = m.split('\n')[0]
        ver = ver_line.split(' ')
        if float(ver[2]) >= 8.24:
            logger.info("coreutils version: {}, required >= 8.24".format(ver[2]))
        else:
            logger.warn("coreutils version: {}, required >= 8.24."
                        "Please ensure that the right version is installed".format(ver[2]))
            sys.exit(1)

    except Exception:
        logger.warn("could not determine coreutils version, required >= 8.24")
        return
```

Comment: You could print the message of that exception by replace "except Exception" with "except Exception as error" and than print the error variable, if this helps you somehow.

Comment: In my experience, it's usually the case that I only want to catch exceptions from known causes (which I know are "okay"). If I wanted to catch all possible exceptions, your code does exactly that. Are you looking for something that will go through and identify possible types of errors and their causes?

Answer (score -1):

with putting the Exceptions as e you can print the exception whatever it is 
You determinate the error by using

```
type(e) == IndexError
```

and then you compare it's values

```
a = ['a', 'b', 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for i in range(0, 20):
    try:
        print(int(a[i]))
    except Exception as e:
        if type(e) == IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            print("ERROR",e)
```